# Find the volume of $P_n = {x \in B_n \textrm{ s.t. } |x_1| < \frac{1}{1000}}$ and the volume of $B_n-P_n$, and determine which is bigger

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Let $B_n$ be the unit ball in $R^n$. We declare $$P_n = \left\{ x\in B_n \textrm{ such that }|x_1| < \frac{1}{1000}\right\} .$$
>   I want to calculate the volume of $P_n$ and $B_n - P_n$ and determine which is bigger.

I tried to use Fubini's theorem here and found $$P_n = V_{n-1}\int_\frac{-1}{1000}^\frac{1}{1000} \left(\sqrt{1-x_1^2}\right)^{n-1}dx_1 ,$$ where $V_{n-1}$ is the volume of the unit ball in $R^{n-1}$. I got to this answer since the volume of a ball in $R^n$ with a radius $r$ is $V_n r^n$.

However here I get stuck since I don't to solve this integral. I couldn't really solve it even with the help of Wolfram Alpha.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It is doubtful that this integral has a "nice" closed form in terms of $n$.

Comment: Maybe there is an other way to solve it?

Comment: Then which volume is bigger: $v(P_n)$ or $v(B_n - P_n)$ ?

Comment: @GabiG for whatever reason I misread your question. My apologies. Let me try again....

Comment: So, what I  thought about is substituting $x_1 = sin(x_1)$, then it will lead to a reduction formula for the integral I wrote. But I still need some help determining which volume is bgger

Comment: $P_n$ is used in the question both for a region in $\Bbb R^n$ and for its volume.

Comment: Whether $P_n$ or $B_n - P_n$ has larger volume depends on $n$.

Answer (score 1):

One can write an explicit formula for the integral in terms of $n$ using a hypergeometric function:
$$\operatorname{vol}(P_n) = 2 s \cdot {}_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}(-n + 1);\frac{3}{2}; s^2\right) V_{n - 1}, \qquad s := \frac{1}{1000}.$$
Unless you have a good deal of intuition for hypergeometric functions, though---I don't---this probably doesn't illuminate the point of the problem much, to say nothing of its second part.

On the other hand, applying Fubini's Theorem in the same way you did but this time to an integral for $V_n$ gives
$$V_n = V_{n - 1} \int_{-1}^1 (1 - x^2)^{(n - 1) / 2} dx,$$
so (after rewriting the integrals using symmetry) we're comparing $$\operatorname{vol}(P_n) = 2 V_{n - 1} \int_0^s (1 - x^2)^{(n - 1) / 2} dx \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad \operatorname{vol}(B_n - P_n) = 2 V_{n - 1} \int_s^1 (1 - x^2)^{(n - 1) / 2} dx ,$$
or just as well, the integrals
$$\int_0^s (1 - x^2)^{(n - 1) / 2} dx \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad \int_s^1 (1 - x^2)^{(n - 1) / 2} dx .$$

Since $(1 - x^2)^{(n - 1) / 2} \leq 1$, the first integral satisfies $$\int_0^s (1 - x^2)^{(n - 1) / 2} \leq s .$$ On the other hand, we have $$\int_0^1 (1 - x^2)^{(n - 1) / 2} dx \geq \int_0^1 \left(1 - (n - 1) x^2\right) dx = \frac{5 - n}{4},$$ so the second integral is $$\int_s^1 (1 - x^2)^{(n - 1) / 2} dx > \frac{5 - n}{4} - s,$$
and hence:

$$\textbf{For small $n$ we have } \operatorname{vol}(B_n - P_n) > \operatorname{vol}(P_n) \textbf{.}$$

On the other hand, the second integral satisfies
$$\int_s^1 (1 - x^2)^{(n - 1) / 2} dx \leq (1 - s) (1 - s^2)^{(n - 1) / 2} \leq (1 - s^2)^{(n - 1) / 2},$$
whereas for large $n$ (explicitly, $n > -2 \log 2 / \log(1 - s)$), a naive comparison for the first integral gives
$$\int_0^s (1 - x^2)^{(n - 1) / 2} dx \geq \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1 - 4^{- 1 / n}} .$$
Expanding the r.h.s. in a series at $\infty$ gives $\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1 - 4^{- 1 / n}} = \sqrt{\frac{\log 2}{2}} n^{-1 / 2} + O(n^{-3 / 2})$. In particular, $\int_0^s (1 - x^2)^{(n - 1) / 2} dx$ decays much more slowly in $n$ than $(1 - s^2)^{(n - 1) / 2}$, so:

$$\textbf{For large $n$ we have } \operatorname{vol}(B_n - P_n) < \operatorname{vol}(P_n) \textbf{.}$$

Comment: I don't think this bound on $n$ is right though as $P_n = \int_{-.001}^{.001}$Vol$B_{n-1}(\sqrt{1-x^2})dx$, while $B_n = \int_{-1}^{1}$Vol$B_{n-1}(\sqrt{1-x^2})dx$.  Even for $n \approx 3000$, Vol$(B_{n-1}(1-a^2))$ is close to 1 all the way up to $a \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}} \approx .01 >> .001$ so there is no way $P_n = \int_{-.001}^{.001}$Vol$B_{n-1}(\sqrt{1-x^2})dx$ can be at least half of $\int_{-1}^{1}$Vol$B_{n-1}(\sqrt{1-x^2})dx$

Comment: Meanwhile there was a solution already given above that answers the question and is much shorter and more elegant than a direct calculation--which still doesn't answer the question of the volume. Why not just go with that solution instead.

Comment: In general, for general positive large $K$ letting $P^K_{xi} = \{x \in B_n; |x_i| \le \frac{1}{K} \}$, this set has half the volume iff $n \geq Y$ for some $Y \in \theta(K^2)$ and not $\theta(K)$. Intuitively $B_{n-1}(\sqrt{1-a^2})dx =(\sqrt{1-a^2})^{n-1}$ has to be about $\frac{1}{2}$ by the time $a$ is $\frac{1}{K}$, and this will only happen if $n$ is that large.

Comment: Typo in my last comment: *Intuitively Vol$(B_{n-1}(\sqrt{1-a^2}) )$ has to be half  Vol$(B_{n-1})$ by the time $a$ is $\frac{1}{K}$; as Vol$(B_{n-1}(\sqrt{1-a^2}) )$  $= (\sqrt{1-a^2})^{n-1}$ Vol$(B_n)$ this will happen only if $n$ is as large as $\theta(K^2)$.

Comment: The solution doesn't claim that the bound $n > -2 \log 2 / \log(1 - s))$ is sufficient to guarantee that $\operatorname{vol}(P_n) > \operatorname{vol}(P_n)$ (it's not). Rather, it claims that bound is sufficient to guarantee the inequality that comes immediately afterward, and that latter inequality is use to establish the asymptotics of $\operatorname{vol}(P_n)$. Consulting a CAS shows that the smallest $n$ where $\operatorname{vol}(P_n)$ first exceeds $\operatorname{vol}(B_n - P_n)$ is $\approx 4.55 \cdot 10^5$.

Comment: Re "Why not just go with that solution instead?": This solution does a few things the other (your) solution did not, including that it (1) answers OP's question about an explicit formula for $P_n$ and (2) answers OP's question for small $n$, not just large $n$. It also shows that we can eliminate the factor of $V_{n-1}$ that occurs in OP's integral and reduce the problem to a comparison of some integrals, after which was can apply some more-or-less straightforward comparisons. Finally, a substantial part of the other answer was added some time after my I posted this answer.

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter could explain their objection? The solution seems pretty inoffensive.

Answer (score 0):

For large enough $n$, the set $P_{ni} = \{x \in B_n; |x_i| \le \frac{1}{1000} \}$ is bigger.

Indeed, for each $i$, let us write as $Q_{ni} = B_n\setminus P_{ni} =  \{x \in B_n; |x_i| > \frac{1}{1000} \}$. So it suffices the show the following inequality:  Vol$(Q_{n1})$ $<\frac{1}{2} \times$Vol$(B_n)$ for $n$ sufficiently large. We do this next.

Then by symmetry each $Q_{ni}$ has the same volume, and of course $\cup_n Q_i \subset B_n$. However, each $x \in B_n$ is in at most $1000^2 =1000000$ of the $Q_{ni}$s [make sure you see why] which implies the following inequality: $\sum_n$ Vol$(Q_{ni}) \le 1000000\times$Vol$(B_n)$, which, as all the $Q_{ni}$s have the same volume, in turn implies the following string of inequalities: Vol$(Q_{n1}) \le \frac{1000000}{n} \times $Vol$(B_n)$ $<\frac{1}{2} \times$Vol$(B_n)$ for $n$ sufficiently large, which yields precisely what you want to show.

---

ETA on the other hand, for general (large) positive $K$, let $P^K_{ni}$ be the set $\{x \in B_n; |x_i| \le \frac{1}{K} \}$. Then the inequality Vol$(P^K_{ni}) < \frac{1}{2} \times$ Vol$(B_n)$ only if $n \ge \theta(K^2)$. Indeed, let us set $a' = \frac{4}{K}$. Then for 
all $a < a'$, we note that Vol$(B_{n-1}(\sqrt{1-a^2})) \geq (\sqrt{1-a^2})^{n-1}$Vol$(B_{n-1})$ $\geq \frac{1}{2}$Vol$(B_{n-1})$ for $n < \frac{K^2}{8}$. This implies

$$\text{vol}(B_n) \ge \int^{a'}_{-a'} \text{Vol}\left(B_{n-1}\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\right) dx$$

$$ > 2 \int^{\frac{1}{K}}_{-\frac{1}{K}} \text{Vol}\left(B_{n-1}\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\right) dx \ \doteq \ 2 \text{Vol}(P^K_{ni}). $$